# filtrar contenido de mi web según la ubicación del usuario

Tags: javascript, html

Hola si quiero que mi página web segmente el contenido según la ubicación del usuario, como me puede servir este código. Quiero mostrar una lista de lugares según la ubicación en el que se encuentre la persona que entre a mi web, en un array de cards de javascript si es posible, al estilo de pedidos ya. Habrá otra opción mejor?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>geo localizacion</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loadLocation () {
    //inicializamos la funcion y definimos  el tiempo maximo ,las funciones de error y exito.
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(viewMap,ViewError,{timeout:1000});
}

//Funcion de exito
function viewMap (position) {
    
    var lon = position.coords.longitude;    //guardamos la longitud
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;     //guardamos la latitud

    var link = "http://maps.google.com/?ll="+lat+","+lon+"&z=14";
    document.getElementById("long").innerHTML = "Longitud: "+lon;
    document.getElementById("latitud").innerHTML = "Latitud: "+lat;

    document.getElementById("link").href = link;

}



function ViewError (error) {
    alert(error.code);
}   



    </script>
    
</head>
<body onload="loadLocation();">
<label id="long"></label> <br/>
<label id="latitud"></label> <br/>
<a id="link" target="_blank">Enlace al mapa</a>


</body>
</html>
```